# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

 <div id="tabsWithStyle" class="style-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="facebook">
        content about Facebook here
    </div>
    <div id="twitter">
         content about Twitter here
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabsWithStyle').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error :

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'
```

I've been searching Google and here as well, I can't seem to find a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not happening with me,its working good!
perhaps, your jquery is conflicting somewhere. try using-

```
<script>
$m=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $m(document).ready(function () {
        $m('#tabsWithStyle').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added your code, and now it works fine.
I still don't understand, but it works.

Comment: @sunny - any pointers for when you have the same sort of scenario where there are lots of occurrences in different js files?