# JQuery Error in MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an ASP .NET MVC 4 Web application and i have included , Jquery-1.10.2 and Jquery-ui-1.10.4 but while executing the application, i am getting following error while creating a tab viewer

Unhandled exception at line 27, column 13 in http://******55707/

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

And the breakpoints to the following tabs function of JQuery

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs(); <----- The break point halts at this point
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Kindly help me with this

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you added css files for jquery UI?

Comment: mention the type of script `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Refer this Stack Overflow Discussion




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907084/0x800a01b6-javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method

Comment: still the error persists